# CMD exiting with code 4 in Azure devops Command line task

Tags: cmd, azure-devops, pmd

I have a command line task running in windows image of Azure DevOps pipeline.
This task after performing pmd.bat  command exiting with code 4. Where as this runs perfectly fine in my local CMD.

```
 task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
   script:  |
       echo starting  execution
       cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
       xcopy *.jar $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\code\
       cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\pmd-bin-6.24.0\bin
       pmd.bat -d "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\code\src\apexcode.cls" -f xml -R "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\code\build\MyApexRule.xml" -reportfile pmd.xml
```

Can anyone help me with what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exiting with code 4 in PMD suggests at least one violation has been detected.

Here are two solutions to make the command work:

1. You can set the parameter `<failurePriority>` to 1 (its default value is 5), so that all violations will be seen as a warning and will be displayed in the build output. And then you can see where the command goes wrong.
2. You can set the parameter `<failOnViolation>` to `false` (its default value is `true`), so that the commands won't fail even if if the validation check fails. The only difference from solution 1 is that no warning messages are displayed.

You can set the parameters in POM file:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <failurePriority>1</failurePriority>
    <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

or set them as properties on pmd.bat inline script.

Comment: No, the issue doesn't seem to be xcopy error because I can see in the log, the xcopy step worked fine and the file is copied proper.

Comment: starting  execution
D:apexcustom-rule-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
1 File(s) copied
Successfully processed 8 files; Failed processing 0 files
D:\a\1\s\code\build\
D:\a\1\s\pmd-bin-6.24.0\bin\..
D:\a\1\s
Aug 17, 2020 6:10:15 AM net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD encourageToUseIncrementalAnalysis
WARNING: This analysis could be faster, please consider using Incremental Analysis: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.24.0/pmd_userdocs_incremental_analysis.html
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '4'.
Finishing: CmdLine

Comment: @priya Exiting without an error message is quite weird. Have you ever tried to run the task without `pmd.pat` command?

Comment: the purpose of the task was to execute the pmd.bat and generate the reportfile...this is working fine in my local...so no issues with the bat file..am unable to understand why is it exiting and failing the task

Comment: @priya Exiting with code 4 in PMD suggests at least one violation has been detected. You can set the parameter `<failurePriority>` to 1 (its default value is 5), so that all violations will be seen as a warning and will be displayed in the build output. And then you can see where the command goes wrong.

Comment: where can I specify this parameter? in rule.xml?

Comment: <ruleset name="MyApexRule"
    xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>
My Custom Rule
    </description>
 <rule name="MyApexRule"
          language="apex"
          class="Apexcustomrule"
          message="Method should not have more than 60 lines of code.">
        <description>
Method should not have more than 60 lines of code.
        </description>
        <priority>3</priority>

Comment: thankyou for the suggestion.. I have included failonviolation property as false on the pmd.bat inline script line ..now it works good without any issue

Comment: Done.Thanks again

Comment: hello, can u help me with this question? thanks in advance -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468067/pmd-analysis-for-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

As Jane Ma-MSFT correctly explained, exit code 4 means, there are some violations detected and the build is failed.

See https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cli_reference.html#exit-status for the documentation.

> 4:    At least one violation has been detected, unless -failOnViolation false is set.

You could adjust your script to add `-failOnVioltation false` if you never want the build to fail and just want to have the report generated:

> Specifies whether PMD exits with non-zero status if violations are found. By default PMD exits with status 4 if violations are found. Disable this feature with `-failOnViolation false` to exit with 0 instead and just output the report.